# Add links to all cells in column of html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to loop through the cells in the second column of an html table, adding a link to the text in each cell. I have a generic base URL, with a hash that should be defined by an integer in the corresponding cell in the first column of the table.

For example, the text in first cell of the second column should link to:

`http://test.example.com/foo.html#1`

Where the `#1` is defined by the integer in the first cell of the first column (`1`). Then repeat for each row, where the integer in each cell of the first column should be used for the hash.

Pure js or jquery would work. I have found this snippet of jquery, which seems like a good start for iterating through each cell in the second column:

```
$('#table1 td:nth-child(2)').each(function(elem) {
    //do something with elem
});
```

Is this jquery method appropriate, and if so, how can I apply the links as described?

As a possible alternative, could I modify the function I use to create the table?:

```
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table1');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(table);
}

createTable(table_input);
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: How is the table created? why not do it at the time the table was rendered? Or you have no control over that table rendering and wish to do this AFTER wards using client side script. You'd loop through each row, read value of first cell and write in second cell.

Comment: @NawedKhan I added my table creation function, if it is appropriate to add the links there. Thanks for the advice, I am still working on my js skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are the one creating the table at the first place it is best to modify the code and render it correctly (as oppose to updating it later on client-side).

Based on your comments and clarification here is the updated code, storing the integer value of first column of each row to use it as url on second column:

```
    function createTable(tableData) {
      var table = document.getElementById('table1');
      var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
      var theUrl = 'http://test.example.com/foo.html#'; //replace with real URL

      tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');

        var i = 1;
        var numValue = '';        
        var content = '';

        rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
          var cell = document.createElement('td');

          numValue = (i==1) ? cellData : numValue ;

          if(i==2){
             content = document.createElement('a');
             content.setAttribute('href', theUrl + numValue);
             content.innerText = cellData ;
          }
          else{
             content = document.createTextNode(cellData);
          }

          cell.appendChild(content);
          row.appendChild(cell);
          i++;
        });

        tableBody.appendChild(row);
      });

      table.appendChild(tableBody);
      document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(table);
    }

    createTable(table_input);
```

Comment: This adds a new column next to every existing column in the table, with the links rendered as text. I would like to use the `table_input` data for the second column, and apply hyperlinks to the text in that column only.

Comment: It is just matter of formatting however you want to format it. I have updated the answer to make it a link. Not sure what 'table_input' is. Your code was originally making a single column table with an integer in each row. You wanted to added a second column with a link using the integer of first column appended to the url after #. Right?

Comment: Apologies for not defining `table_input`. This is a list of lists, where each list is the data for each row. The table is 19 columns by 31 rows. I would like to modify the text in the 2nd column by adding hyperlinks, not add any new columns.

Comment: I have rewritten the code based on the feedback and clarification

Comment: Yes, this is so close! However, the cells in the 2nd column are showing a text string, instead of an actual hyperlink. Such as (for the first cell) `<a href='http://test.example.com/foo.html#1'>CSU</a>`. In this case, the string `CSU` should be hyperlinked.

Comment: That is because createTextNode does what it sounds like: creates a text node which cannot have html. I have updated the code to create anchor element, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the following code:

```
rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
  var cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
  row.appendChild(cell);
});
```

to

```
for (var i=0; i<rowData.length;i++)
{
    var cell = document.createElement('td'); 
    if (i==1)
    {   
        var link=document.createElement("a");
        link.href="http://test.example.com/foo.html#"+(i+1);
        link.text=rowData[i];
        cell.appendChild(link);
    }
    else
        cell.textContent=rowData[i];    
    row.appendChild(cell);
}
```

Comment: This results in every cell in the entire table hyperlinked, with the # value corresponding to the column number. The hyperlinks are applied correctly, but I would like to apply only to the second column, using the data value in the first column of the same row for the hash.